# CMake: target_include_directories and #include

Tags: cmake

I have the following layout. It is basically a certain class, and within its directory there is a subdirectory containing unit tests:

[image]

The class being tested is built like this:

```
add_library(experimental_run PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/experiments/experimental_run/experimental_run.cpp)
target_link_libraries(experimental_run PUBLIC nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json)
```

(this is the outermost CMakeLists in the image).
The tests-directory's CMakeLists.txt's contents are as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

add_executable(test_experimental_run_obj ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test_experimental_run.cpp)
target_compile_options(test_experimental_run_obj PUBLIC -pg -g -O2)
target_link_libraries(test_experimental_run_obj PUBLIC experimental_run GTest::GTest GTest::Main)
target_include_directories(
        test_experimental_run_obj PUBLIC
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/experiments/experimental_run/)
```

Essentially, first I am building the class as a library,
and then try to build the unit tests linking them towards
the library *and* including the appropriate directory
with `target_include_directories` and `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}`, where the latter
stores the root directory of the project.
Now this looks like I am effectively telling `CMake` "Feel free to look into the included
directories for anything you find in my #includes." However, my unit-test file
has it in red:

[image]

and prompts me to include the files using "../"
Now, why then I bothered to have the `target_include_directories` in the first place,
if I am to explicitly show the location anyway? Isn't the main idea
to make the whole thing flexible, without code duplication?
What am I missing?

EDIT: now that I went ahead and *did* include the "../"-prefix, the unit tests fail to compile, since the linked library `experimental_run` is non-existent. No wonder, since `CLion` does not seem to recognize it as something it needs to `build`.
EDIT: I've figured out one thing for now. `CMAKE_PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` refers to the directory of where *this* _very CMakeLists resides, i.e. referring to the `project`'s argument. This way, I can load the outermost library as a `CMake` project, but however cannot link against it inside the tests still.

(final) UPDATE:
Let's say I found a "workaround" this by adding

```
set(SOURCES ./test_experimental_run.cpp ../experimental_run.cpp)
set(TARGET test_experimental_run_obj)
```

into the CMakeLists of the unit-tests directory, and to no surprise it
compiles and works fine. If I remove he second `*.cpp` file, however,
and add `experimental_run` to `target_link_libraries`, I get

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable test_experimental_run_obj
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lexperimental_run
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Essentially the question is how to test the library assuming it is compiled,
and without having to specify its source code inside the unit-testing code.
Appreciate your time, I am yet developing my modus operandi with CMake,
so even shaping the right question is challenging for me right now.

Comment: Do you have an actual compilation error or this is just in your IDE?

Comment: Please include the **specific** error you are receiving from the compiler in your question post. With all of the descriptions of the different issues (some solved?), it is very hard to understand what the actual problem is...

Comment: It sounds like the ordering of your target creation is incorrect. You have to be sure CMake has defined the `experimental_run` target (via `add_library`) *before* using it in a `target_link_libraries()` call. Without a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it is difficult to suggest solutions.